# Эквалайзер в Raspberry Pi и moc

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Хочу сделать цветомузыку на Raspberry Pi, как работать со светодиодной лентой я знаю. В rpi установлен проигрыватель moc, музыка играет в нём. Как мне из скрипта python получить текущие частоты, чтобы передать их на светодиодную ленту?

Comment: Выполнять Фурье-анализ текущего кадра, если производительность rpi позволит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как пример, с которого можно начать можно написать что-то подобное:

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
import wave
import pyaudio

test_wav_request = requests.get("http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/WAV/Media-Convert/Media-Convert_test6_PCM_Stereo_VBR_16SS_8000Hz.wav")
if test_wav_request.status_code != 200:
    print("Не могу скачать WAV. Код:", test_wav_request.status_code)
    exit(1)


wav_file = BytesIO(initial_bytes=test_wav_request.content)
wav = wave.open(wav_file)
(nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname) = wav.getparams()
# content = wav.readframes(nframes)
width_to_bits = {1: np.int8, 2: np.int16, 4: np.int32}
width_to_bits_ = {1: 8, 2: 16, 4: 32}
width_pyaudio = {1: pyaudio.paInt8, 2: pyaudio.paInt16, 4: pyaudio.paInt32}

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=width_pyaudio[sampwidth],
                    channels=nchannels,
                    rate=framerate,
                    input=False,
                    output=True)


print((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname))

sample_size = 4 * 512


def normalize(samples, bits_per):
    return [s / 2**bits_per for s in samples]

# Для примера возьмем последовательно 4 сэмпла размером 4*512 кадров.
# Для данного файла частота 8000 кадров в секунду, то есть возьмем кадров за 0.25 секунд
stream.start_stream()
for i in range(1, 5):
    sample = wav.readframes(sample_size)
    # Для данного файла точно известно, что количество каналов 2
    data = normalize(np.fromstring(sample, width_to_bits[sampwidth]), width_to_bits_[sampwidth])

    stream.write(sample)

    left_channel = data[::2]
    right_channel = data[1::2]

    furier_left = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(left_channel))
    furier_right = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(right_channel))

    # Не знаю, что делают с разными каналами, но можно их объединить
    spectrum = np.hstack((furier_left[: int(len(furier_left) / 2)], furier_right[: int(len(furier_right) / 2)]))

    Hz = np.fft.fftfreq(len(left_channel), d=0.25)
    Hz *= framerate

    # По какой-то неизвестной причине в furier_left лишний элемент
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
    plt.plot(Hz[:len(Hz) // 2], 10 * np.log10(furier_left[:-1]))
    plt.ylabel("dB")
    plt.xlabel("Hz. Number: " + str(i))
stream.stop_stream()
plt.show()
```

Данный скрипт скачает тестовый wav файл с блеянием овцы, и построит 4 графика - каждые 0.25 секунд извлекается звук, нормализуется, проводит преобразование Фурье. Затем считает значения децибел и выводит график - по оси X - Герцы, по оси Y - Децибелы. Вот один из графиков - https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7fMi.jpg. 4 графика на одной картинке: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEzNk.jpg Честно говоря, я не знаю, похоже ли это на "эквалайзер", потому что гугл говорит, что эквалайзер - это устройство.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую! Ну а как вообще делают визуализации в WinAmp том же самом, да и в moc есть тоже

Comment: Не могу сказать - оси-то там нигде не подписаны. Думаю, что примерно также. Можно взять какое-нибудь количество октав и усреднять результаты по ним - тогда получится не график, а гистограмма, прямо как в WinAmp-подобных визулизациях. Можно брать значения не децибел, а просто коэффициенты после Фурье - тоже должно во времени прыгать в разные стороны.

Comment: Да, вот отсюда возникает вопрос, как взять эти значения у текущего аудио потока?

Comment: @Jeid, используя moc навряд ли можно получить сырой поток - moc это стороннее приложение, не библиотека для Python и не факт, что у него есть такие возможности. Я добавлю в ответ пример с PyAudio.

Comment: @Jeid, я обновил пример с воспроизведением аудио. Можно посмотреть только изменения в истории. Точно так же его можно повторить с библиотеками для других форматов, например, PyMedia или pygame - у всех них схожие API. Мой пример не очень функционален, потому что отображает графики после воспроизведения - это легко меняется методом `animate` из `matplotlib`. Вам, вероятно, придется использовать библиотеку шустрее. Например, plotly. Самое сложное здесь - это Фурье и все, что с ним связано, а рисовалки по сравнению с этим тривиальны.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое!